# Canon LBP2900B is not working with elementary OS Freya

Tags: printer

The Driver for the printer has been installed.

However the printer does not respond to print requests. It only displays a message that the page has been printed. It works fine with other operating systems

Comment: I believe that in this case there shouldn't be any big differences between elementary OS and Ubuntu, and it seems that this printer doesn't work well in Linux. Anyway, you could try the Ubuntu answers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457774/driver-canon-lbp-2900 http://askubuntu.com/questions/487627/how-to-install-canon-lbp2900b-printer-in-14-04-lts-i-tried-the-method-for-lbp2

Comment: this should be on askubuntu

Comment: @cipricus While the problem may also exist on some Ubuntu systems, a version after 14.04 may have fixed this, and so the question becomes more elementary specific. Answering in multiple places is not necessarily bad, especially with more specifics.

Comment: @LewisGoddard - you are certainly right, especially with printer drivers that may be absent and help is welcome from all directions. I meant: *this should be on askubuntu TOO*

Comment: Follow the steps described here http://askubuntu.com/a/617206 and it should work like a charm. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem for a hp printer by installing the latest driver directly from the hp homepage. It seems like canon is offering a driver for the "Canon i-SENSYS LBP2900" which could be similar enough to work. [Link to German support site](http://www.canon.de/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp2900.aspx?type=drivers&language=&os=Linux%20(64-bit)#)
Unfortunately, I was unable to find the same link on the English support site so. Give it a try.